# Should I include zeroes in my dataset for a machine learning study?

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataset

I am trying to predict the taxi demand in New York city depending on pickup location and hour. I am constructing a dataset of taxi pickups grouped by the tracts in NYC and hour of the day. However, there are tracts where no taxi pickup took place for a certain time.

Should I include those observations with zero pickups in my dataset?
It gives me more information if I add them, but on the other hand my dataset gets much bigger and, hence, computational costs increase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should include those observations, because they represent meaningful variation in your data - a zero is not the same as missing data. In general, whether zeroes should be included depends on your goal. For most goals that I can think of, it's worth including them.

However, there are possible goals for which these points wouldn't matter. As an example, if your question related primarily to areas with the highest number of pickups, areas with no pickups could probably be omitted without much loss.

Comment: I agree. My goal is to predict the taxi demand depending on pickup location and hour. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @vranjes I've edited your question and my response to clarify this. Please see if the edits capture your meaning correctly, and if the answer addresses your question.